# Var hundreds = parseInt(num_images / 100)

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie so sorry in advance for a probably novice question.

Can someone please let me know what this specific javascript code does? Programmer left me high and dry and I have to fix this myself TODAY!

```
Var hundreds = parseInt(num_images / 100)
```

UPDATE: Here is the full code - trying to change the price of a single image to $15 instead of $10 (which is what it previously was) I believe the issue is in the line that I questioned. Please let me know how I can change this. Really appreciate all the assistance!!!

```
var totalcost = 0;
        var cdcost = 0;
        var cdtext = "";
        var merchandisecost = 0;
        var makecd = false;

        function GetCDCost(num_images) {
            var hundreds = parseInt(num_images / 100);
            var remainder = num_images % 100;

            if (remainder < 4) {
                return (135 * hundreds) + (15 * remainder);
            }
            else if (remainder <= 15) {
                return (135 * hundreds) + 65;
            }
            else if (remainder <= 25) {
                return (135 * hundreds) + 85;
            }
            else if (remainder <= 50) {
                return (135 * hundreds) + 105;
            }
            else if (remainder <= 100) {
                return (135 * hundreds) + 135;
            }
        }

        function UpdateCheckoutCost() {
            var html_string = "";
            var poster_flag = false; // Is there a poster(s) in this order? 
            var no_shipping = true; // Shipping flag;

            cdcost = GetCDCost(favorites.length);
            if (favorites.length < 4) {
                cdtext = "CD - " + favorites.length + " pictures @ $15/each";
            }
            else if (favorites.length <= 15) {
                cdtext = "CD - 15 Images";
            }
            else if (favorites.length <= 25) {
                cdtext = "CD - 25 Images";
            }
            else if (favorites.length <= 50) {
                cdtext = "CD - 50 Images";                  
            }
            else if (favorites.length <= 100) {
                cdtext = "CD - 100 Images";
            }
            else if (favorites.length > 100) {
                cdtext = "CD - " + favorites.length + " Images";
            }
```

Comment: `v` in `Var` should be small. See [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Always use a radix param in the parseInt function, as well.

Comment: parseInt is used to convert string to integer but in this i assume num_images is an integer because we are performing math on it. i dont think we need parseInt

Answer (score 1):

1. **Converts Floats to integers:** It removes the the decimal part of number. Suppose value of num_images is 233 then num_images/100 will return 2.33 and parseInt(num_images / 100) will remove .33 part and return 2.

   ```
   var num_images = 233
   num_images/100 // equals 2.33
   parseInt(num_images/100) //equals 2
   ```
2. **Parses Integer for String if possible:**

   ```
   typeof "123" //String
   typeof parseInt("123") //type=number and value =123
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates how many hundreds of images you have:

```
num_images = 65535
num_images /100 = 655.35
parseInt(655) = 655
hundreds = 655
```

or using a code snippet:

```js
var num_images = 65535
document.write('num_images: '+ num_images  + '<br>')
document.write('num_images/100: ' +num_images /100 + '<br>')
document.write('parseInt(num_images /100) :'+parseInt(num_images /100)+ '<br>')
```

Comment: typo in the first line, `(x / 100)` won't magically return an integer (in this case it would be `NaN`), `parseInt(655)` does indeed return the same number but that's not the reason why it is used in the code shown in the question. So why is there an upvote?

Comment: So how would I change the price to reflect $15 instead of 10?

Comment: This line looks correct: `return (135 * hundreds) + (15 * remainder);` What is the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

```
var hundreds = parseInt(num_images / 100);
```

Will divided "num_images" by 100, lowest round it and put the result in hundreds variable.
Typicaly if "num_images" equals 25015, divided by 100 the result is 250.15, rounded, the result is 250. 
**It will cut unit and decade (250xx).**

Comment: Isn't that what the existing code was doing (except always rounding down)?

parseInt(25015 / 100); //250
Math.round(25015 / 100); //250